# Is there a way to get JSF to work with Generic setters and getters

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to get JSF to work with generic entities as described below:

**Property.java**

```
    public interface MyProperty<T> {
        void setMyValue(T value);
        T getMyValue(T value);
    }
```

In my application `T` could `Date`, `String`, `Integer` or `Long` only

**MyObject.java**

```
    public class MyObject {
        List<MyProperty<?>> properties;

        public List<MyProperty<?>> getProperties() {
            return properties;
        }
    }
```

**MyController.java**

```
@Named("controller")
@RequestScoped
public class MyController {

    MyObject myObject;
    public void setMyObject(MyObject myObject) { this.myObject = myObject; };
    public MyObject getMyObject() { return myObject; } ;
}
```

**edit.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head><title></title></h:head><h:body>
    <h:form>
    <ui:repeat  var="property" value="#{controller.myObject.properties}">
        <h:inputText value="#{property.myValue}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
        <h:commandButton action="#{controller.save}" value="save"/>
    </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as JSF tries to find a setter on myObject with the signature:

```
void setMyValue(String value);
```

Which obviously doesn't exist since type erasure results in the method having the following signature:

```
void setMyValue(Object value);
```

Is there any way to get round this?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is unclear, but, the answer is definitely **YES**, JSF can be accompanied with generics.

Though, it depends on how *wise* you are using generics and, ultimately, on the question whether you do understand generics at all.

As far as I can tell from your example, you are going to use generic interface as a *wrapper* to the object contained in the implemented class.

### Use classes with *wrapped getters/setters*

With this approach you do not directly deal with `MyInterface` implementations, but rather with its contents, as defined by the interface methods.

Base interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    void setMyValue(T value);
    T getMyValue();
}
```

Implementing class:

```
public class MyString implements MyInterface<String> {

    private String myValue;

    public MyString(String myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    public void setMyValue(String value) {
        this.myValue = value;
    }

    public String getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return myValue;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class MyInteger implements MyInterface<Integer> {

    private Integer myValue;

    public MyInteger(Integer myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    public void setMyValue(Integer value) {
        this.myValue = value;
    }

    public Integer getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(myValue);
    }

}
```

Managed bean (with *anonymous class*):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyInterfaceBean {

    private MyString myString;
    private MyInteger myInteger;
    private MyInterface<Float> myFloat;

    public MyInterfaceBean() {
        myString = new MyString("String");
        myInteger = new MyInteger(1);
        myFloat = new MyInterface<Float>() {

            private Float myValue;

            public void setMyValue(Float value) {
                this.myValue = value;
            }

            public Float getMyValue() {
                return myValue;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return Float.toString(myValue);
            }

        };
        myFloat.setMyValue(3.1f);
    }

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString.getMyValue();
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString.setMyValue(myString);
    }

    public Integer getMyInteger() {
        return myInteger.getMyValue();
    }

    public void setMyInteger(Integer myInteger) {
        this.myInteger.setMyValue(myInteger);
    }

    public Float getMyFloat() {
        return myFloat.getMyValue();
    }

    public void setMyFloat(Float myFloat) {
        this.myFloat.setMyValue(myFloat);
    }

    public String action() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The view:

```
<h:outputText value="String: #{myInterfaceBean.myString}"/>
<br/>
<h:outputText value="Integer: #{myInterfaceBean.myInteger}"/>
<br/>
<h:outputText value="Float: #{myInterfaceBean.myFloat}"/>
<br/>
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="String: "/><h:inputText value="#{myInterfaceBean.myString}"/>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="Integer: "/><h:inputText value="#{myInterfaceBean.myInteger}"/>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="Float: "/><h:inputText value="#{myInterfaceBean.myFloat}"/>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myInterfaceBean.action}"/>
</h:form>
```

### Use classes with *@FacesConverter*

Another approach is to use a `@FacesConverter` so that JSF would know how to convert strings in input fields to objects that implement `MyInterface`.

Managed bean (with *anonymous class*):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyInterfaceBean {

    private MyString myString;
    private MyInteger myInteger;
    private MyInterface<Float> myFloat;

    public MyInterfaceBean() {
        myString = new MyString("String");
        myInteger = new MyInteger(1);
        myFloat = new MyInterface<Float>() {

            private Float myValue;

            public void setMyValue(Float value) {
                this.myValue = value;
            }

            public Float getMyValue() {
                return myValue;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return Float.toString(myValue);
            }

        };
        myFloat.setMyValue(3.1f);
    }

    public MyString getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(MyString myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public MyInteger getMyInteger() {
        return myInteger;
    }

    public void setMyInteger(MyInteger myInteger) {
        this.myInteger = myInteger;
    }

    public MyInterface<Float> getMyFloat() {
        return myFloat;
    }

    public void setMyFloat(MyInterface<Float> myFloat) {
        this.myFloat.setMyValue(myFloat.getMyValue());//not to lose this anonymous class, can substitute for other implementation directly
    }

    public String action() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Converters:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "myStringConverter")
public class MyStringConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        MyString obj = new MyString(value);
        return obj;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof MyString) || (value == null)) {
            return null;
        }
        return ((MyString)value).getMyValue();
    }

}
```

and

```
@FacesConverter(value = "myIntegerConverter")
public class MyIntegerConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        MyInteger obj = null;
        try {
            Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(value);
            obj = new MyInteger(integer);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Integer could not be parsed from string: " + value));
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof MyInteger) || (value == null)) {
            return null;
        }
        return ((MyInteger)value).getMyValue().toString();
    }

}
```

and

```
@FacesConverter(value = "myFloatConverter")
public class MyFloatConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        MyInterface<Float> obj = null;
        try {
            Float floatValue = Float.valueOf(value);
            obj = new MyInterface<Float>() {

                private Float myValue;

                public void setMyValue(Float value) {
                    this.myValue = value;
                }

                public Float getMyValue() {
                    return myValue;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return Float.toString(myValue);
                }

            };
            obj.setMyValue(floatValue);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Float could not be parsed from string: " + value));
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof MyInterface) || (value == null)) {
            if(!(((MyInterface)value).getMyValue() instanceof Float)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return ((MyInterface)value).getMyValue().toString();
    }

}
```

The view:

```
<h:outputText value="String: #{myInterfaceBean.myString}"/>
<br/>
<h:outputText value="Integer: #{myInterfaceBean.myInteger}"/>
<br/>
<h:outputText value="Float: #{myInterfaceBean.myFloat}"/>
<br/>
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="String: "/><h:inputText value="#{myInterfaceBean.myString}" converter="myStringConverter"/>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="Integer: "/><h:inputText value="#{myInterfaceBean.myInteger}" converter="myIntegerConverter"/>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="Float: "/><h:inputText value="#{myInterfaceBean.myFloat}" converter="myFloatConverter"/>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myInterfaceBean.action}"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I've added some more information to try to clarify the question. Hopefully the question now makes a little more sense. If not please let me know :-)