# ClassCastException Java with list iterator

Tags: java, jsf, iterator, classcastexception

I have a very strange error in my code. I am using iterators since the beginning of my project and I never had problems but here I can't understand what's going on.

I have a model class

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int field1;
    private String field2;
    private List<OtherObject> field3;
    private Date field4
    ...
    // + Getters and setters
    // + Override equals method
}
```

A class with a parameters of MyObject type

```
public class FooClass implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<MyObject> list;
    // + getters and setters
}
```

And I have an other class using MyObject

```
public class MyController {
    .....
    public static void AMethod(FooClass value) {
        List<MyObject> myList = value.getList();
        Iterator<MyObject> iterator = myList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            MyObject temp = iterator.next();  // error on this line
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My objects are displayed in a JSF view by using the following code:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{fooClass.list}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{fooClass.listAll}" var="obj" 
                   itemValue="#{obj}" itemLabel="#{obj.field2}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.MyObject
```

Have any got any suggestions?

Comment: The error shows that List contains String type, and you are trying to cast to "MyObject"

Comment: Do you accidentally use Fooclass.list as a raw `List` somewhere? That would let you insert a string to `myList`.

Comment: The code you have shown cannot throw that exception. There is something wrong somewhere else. How are you populating `FooClass.list`?

Comment: Can you provide full code? seems like you are adding string elements in the list, hence the exception.

Comment: In fact I am filling this list with JSF. The composant is a primefaces selectCheckboxMenu. So if it contains a string, that come from here. I  will search this way.

Comment: Can you post the JSF-Tag who controlls the List?

Comment: `<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{fooClass.list}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{fooClass.listAll}" var="obj" itemValue="#{obj}" itemLabel="#{obj.field2}" />  
         </p:selectCheckboxMenu>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of 'design' of HTTP protocol: when request is sent to the server all data are sent as `String`s. So, JSF interprets them as `String`s as well, because you didn't explicitly tell that the object to be expected is of your particular class, in your case `MyObject`. This happens because EL that handles all view-model communicaion is based on reflection and you know that generics in Java is a compile-time phenomenon due to type erasure: generic information is not available at runtime.

So basically after you submit the form your list consists of plain `String` objects and not of your `MyObject` instances, as you seem to expect: generic information was replaced by JSF EL after form had been submitted. That's why you got `ClassCastException`. You can check the types of elements your list contains by yourself if you put a breakpoint on an action(listener) method, or setter method.

To resolve the situation you either need to explicitly tell JSF to use a `Converter` (by specifying `converter` attribute, or by nesting `<f:converter>` tag), or by switching to plain array (to `MyObject[]`) instead of a `List<MyObject>`.

You can find more information, as well as some solutions, in my answer to [JSF and type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16433778/1820286) question.

Comment: Thank you so much! Working with a converter. And very clear response!