# JSF /Primefaces select one menu causing issues

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, runtime-error

My `index.xhtml` looks like

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{tBean.selectedChartType}"
                    converter="entityConverter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{tBean.chartTypes}" var="chart"
                        itemLabel="#{chart}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This presents ENUM list from my managed bean

```
private List<ChartType> chartTypes = Arrays.asList(ChartType.values());
```

My Enum

```
public enum ChartType {

    Line("line"), Spiral_Line("spline"), Area("area"), Spiral_Area("areaspline");
    private String code;

    private ChartType(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Now when I run this .jsf on browser sometimes it throw error :

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: http://xxxx/index.sf
Line Number 54, Column 733:
```

When I look at the source code I have found

```
&nbsp;
```

which is causing this error I guess.

I am using `JSF 2.2.0` and `Primefaces 3.5`

could someone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF and type safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433250/jsf-and-type-safety)

Comment: @skuntsel How is it possible duplicate ?

Comment: That's a close vote made by mistake for sure, but I can't unfortunately undo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to help the asker, but perhaps can help someone: I got this same error and the only way I could get around it was adding the attribute `contentType="text/html"` to my `<f:view>`, as in

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
...
  <p:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="test" itemValue="test"/>
  </p:selectOneMenu>
...
</f:view>
```

This occurs, afaik, because `p:selectOneMenu` renders a `&nbsp;` and this character is not a xml entity. As my page uses `DOCTYPE XHTML 1.0 Transitional`, this causes the error to occur.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Try as the following configuration in `faces-config.xml`

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>java.lang.Enum</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>javax.faces.convert.EnumConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

page

```
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{tBean.selectedChartType}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{tBean.chartTypes}" var="chart" itemLabel="#{chart}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: As your page, it is cause of the converter

Comment: I will give it a go but I don't think so we have to register this enumconverter as JSF has alrady built-in converter for enum. I think my mistake was to use any converter for ENUM Select one menu.

Comment: ^ Not even in faces-config.xml